# Numerical solution of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following one-dimensional PDE $$\partial_tv(t,x)+b(x)\partial_xv(t,x)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)\partial_x^2(t,x)+(v-2v^{-1})(t,x)=0 \quad \text{ for } t \in (0,T)$$ with the boundary condition $$v(T,\cdot)=c,$$ where $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

The problem is that the function $x \mapsto x-2x^{-1}$ is only locally Lipschitz continuous. Is it still possible to solve the PDE numerically by simulating the corresponding backward SDE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ambiguous notations. is $v'(x)=\partial_x v(x,t)$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Exactly. Sorry for the confusion.